# How to take over arguments after virtual env activation in batch and Python

Tags: python, batch-file

I want to execute python script by batch file.
when I do that , I want to take over argument to python scipt.
But, after activation of venv, it is not possible to take over the argument.

The batch file I made is the following:
It does not work.

```
SET file=%~nx1

rem activate virtual env
CALL ..\Script\activate.bat

rem execute python in virtual env with argument
python train.py --data .\data\%file%
```

Comment: Try adding `echo %*` after the `call` command. I believe you'll find that the arguments are still available.

Comment: Thank you for your answer！　It works well. Your comment helps me. Thank you.

Comment: I cannot see any issue with the code you submitted. Altbough you should not be using just `python` in a batch file. At the very least use `python.exe` and preferably `"A:\bsolute\PathTo\python.exe"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try specific file instead of %~nx1.
'%' may be the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I want to use various files as input. So I'm thinking of passing it as an argument by dragging and dropping the file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).